# Computed Fields In JAXB Object

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a computed field in a JAXB object. Here's a quick mockup of what I want:

```
public class Person {

    public Date dateOfBirth;

    // person is eligible for benefits at age 65
    public Date getDateEligibleForBenefits() {

    }
}
```

To make this slightly more difficult, these classes are generated via XSD files:

```
<xs:schema>
<xs:element name="Person" type="Person" />
<xs:complexType name="Person">
    <xs:element name="dateOfBirth" />
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have created an incomplete xsd scheme. Right:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="Person" type="Person" />
<xsd:complexType name="Person">
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="dateOfBirth" type="xsd:dateTime" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

"complexType" must include "sequence" and only then "element". I do not recommend writing java class manually, use special tools to generate code, like **XJC**. [Read this manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbah.html)

Finally you get a class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Person", propOrder = {
    "dateOfBirth"
})
public class Person {

    @XmlElement(name = "dateOfBirth", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar dateOfBirth;

    .....

}
```